# SSIS ETL Data Flow task - size of Extract

Tags: ssis, etl, dataflow

log the size of the Data flow task extract

I am running a dataflow task in which I am extracting data from a source. I wanted to know the size (kb or mb) of data extract.

I do not want to use script component, because its going to slow the etl process.

Comment: What are you measuring? The output file?

Comment: size of data extract, by record or by file? if for each records, maybe you can just convert record to binary, if for file, you can put script component out of data flow and this will not impact performance.

Comment: I am looking for the size of record ;  each record (row) that the source is extracting.